# How can I prevent Firebase auth users from changing their email address by themselves?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

According to firebase doc, it seems that client side SDK allows email address as well as user profile information to be updated directly.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#update_a_users_profile

If I build an android app without any UI workflow for users to change email address, I am confident that majority, 99.99%+ of the regular users, will use the app as intended.

However, if certain users investigate/reverse-engineers into the app, learns that it uses the firebase, wouldn't it be possible for them to debug and invoke any one of the Firebase Auth client SDK methods provided? (e.g. Wouldn't it be possible for hacker to change email address [not supposed to be allowed in my app after initial registration] & change photo url to point to something inappropriate images?

With Firestore database, I could use security rules to prevent read/writes, but I wasn't sure how I could do something similar in Firebase authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible for users to get a hold of the token that would be used to call the backend APIs exposed by Firebase Authentication that would normally be used by the SDK.  There is no equivalent to database security rules.

The fact of the matter is that users normally *should* be able to change their email address, as they might actually need to change email provider at some point.  If your app doesn't allow this for some reason, and you have a hard requirement to only use the email address provided by the authentication provider(s) you allow, you should consider writing that value to a database at the time the user account is created.  Then, use security rules to prevent the user from changing it there.  From that point on, you would only ever trust the value initially written to the database, and never use the email address from the auth provider.

You would probably want to handle writing to the database from a [Cloud Functions auth onCreate trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events), so that you control all the logic.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I meant to say, I am fine with user changing their email address through the approved workflow as people often change their primary address. However, it seems impossible to prevent malicious users from changing emails (or usernames/photos) without the my app server knowing about it.

Comment: If I have to maintain a separate database to keep the source of truth, then I wouldn't be able to take advantage of majority of Firebase Auth's features, such as email actions, password management, profiles, etc. I guess I will evaluate cost between in-house auth management development VS risks of a few users polluting their profile data, and decide what todo.

Answer (score 0):

I am now facing the same issue, and I think I will just not worry about the 0.01%. This is mostly because if they change their own email with Firebase Authentication via reverse-engineering and my web server is unaware of their new email, this would not have any impact on the other genuine users except maybe not being able to find them (email is only used in searches for now).